# eval() and base64_decode() again

Tags: php, encoding, base64, eval, obfuscation

As always, the bottom line of any discussion about using **`eval()`** is: *it is better to avoid using it as much as possible wherever there's another approach because it is tricky and dangerous*; this why I've never had interests reading about it, well until now..

I tried to encode a simple function through some [website](http://www.phpencode.org/) which uses **`eval(base64_decode())`**, it obfuscated this function:

```
<?php
    echo 'Hello There!<hr />';
    for( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {
        echo( '5x'.$i.'='.(string)($i*5)."\n" . '<br />' );
    }
?>
```

When I tested the encoded output on my local machine it worked exactly like it should, *However* I tried to decode it using two other websites ( [ddecode](http://ddecode.com/phpdecoder/) , [tools4noobs](http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/base64_decode/)  ) the result was a whole different thing, same thing if i replace `eval()` with `print()` >>

```
if(!function_exists("YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8")){
   function YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8($g,$b=0){
      $a=implode("\n",$g);$d=array(655,236,40);
      if($b==0) $f=substr($a,$d[0],$d[1]);
      elseif($b==1)$f=substr($a,$d[0]+$d[1],$d[2]);
      else $f=trim(substr($a,$d[0]+$d[1]+$d[2]));
     return($f);
   }
}
```

What's going on here! did the decoding fail or the encoded data is something different than the one I entered in the first website - *malicious code for example although it looks like the output represents some encoding mechanism*, But if I am wrong how come it worked like it should, and if am right then such thing cannot be decoded?

Also, is it safe to use eval() in this way? considering I got the encoded string from a strange website. Or it is better to implement it by myself? even though the **`base64_encode()`** encodes same function into a different output which is if decoded it returns the same function.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your phpencode web site seems to use multiple levels of obfuscation, not just base64 encoding. It seems to have gzip compression and checksums in there too.

Comment: @GregHewgill Thanks, I thought that, sort of, still is it safe to use eval like that, first: with the code obtained from that website? second: by own implementing some other code with aid of base64_encode()?

Comment: It's just an obfuscation preface, typically just loading the payload from a different file offset. Delays deobfuscation about five minutes more. -- Stop going on and off about if that's *safe*. Running untrusted code is your decision, whether you use `include` or the `eval` wrapper.

Comment: @mario many thanks, with much respect I don't think asking more experienced programmers about what is and what is not safe isn't something ugly, especially in my current case because I've never used `eval()` before.

Comment: As evil as eval can be, I only avoid it for reasons of speed. It's about 220% slower than native code and prevents any chance of opcode optimizations. It would be a really interesting challenge to see if you could obfuscate your own code using PHP 5.6's new splat operator, converting stuff to octal, hex, unicode, escaping chars, etc.